# Bind_Result always return 0

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

This is my code. I'm trying to get the value accountId returned and assigned to $accountId but I always get 0 returned. The query is fine it return the value I want in PHP my admin but it doesn't return it here. Do you know why?

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli($SQLhost, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, $SQLdatabase);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT accountId FROM Account WHERE accountUsername=? AND accountPassword=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username,$password);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($accountId);

    $_SESSION['accountId'] = $accountId;
```

Comment: Can you provide some debugging values? echo out the number of the rows and a var_dump of $accountId

Comment: I add $stmt->fetch(); and it work at the end

Answer (score 0):

The working code:
        $mysqli = new mysqli($SQLhost, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword, $SQLdatabase);

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT accountId FROM Account WHERE accountUsername=? AND accountPassword=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username,$password);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($accountID);

    $stmt -> fetch();

    $_SESSION['accountId'] = $accountID;
```